# Is it possible to get both Interger and String value from one HashMap method?

Tags: android, hashmap

I want to merge my two Hashmap methods. One method is for getting user ID and the other is for getting user String information. But I want to get all information from one hashmap method. Is it possible? If it is, how can I do this in my getuserdetails hashmap method?

**Method 1:**

```
public HashMap<String, Integer> getUid() {

        HashMap<String, Integer> uid = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Log.d("database", "before uid put");
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            uid.put("uid",cursor.getInt(0));
        }
        cursor.close();
        // return user

        return uid;
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(3));
    }
    cursor.close();
    // return user
    Log.d(TAG, "Fetching user from Sqlite: " + user.toString());

    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest approach here would be to create a User object with fields for id, name, email and created_at, something like this:

```
public class User {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private String email;
  private Date createdAt; // Or use string here, whichever you want

  // create or generate getters and setters for above fields
}
```

You can then get the data from the database using your query and create a user:

```
public User getUserDetails() {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    User user = new User();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        user.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        user.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        user.setEmail(cursor.getString(2));
        user.setCreatedAt(cursor.getString(3));
    }
    else {
        cursor.close();
        return null; // There wasn't a user to be found
    }
    cursor.close();

    return user;
}
```

Now your method creates a `User` object, containing all required information.

Answer (score 2):

Make a class with uid and name veriable And Create a hashmap method as a return type of this class. Hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap together in a class like

```
public class Info {
   public int uid; 
   public String name;
}
```

and have a `HashMap<String, Info>`